# Which ship has the most prolific "recurring" role in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, spaceship, props

Obviously there are many recurring characters over the span of the Star Trek canon.

Some obvious examples:   Q, Lwaxana Troi, Gowron, Lursa, B'Etor, Adm. Nechayev, Lt. Barclay, Gul Dukat

## What ship appears in the most episodes/films?

What is not admitted:

- Enterprises
- Runabouts
- Defiant
- Voyager
- support craft for the above ships (Delta Flyer, shuttlecraft)
- space stations and docks
- ships from different eras with the same name which are not the same ship.   (Do **not** argue that we technically don't know whether a TOS-era and a TNG-era ship are the same or not - there's no precedent for that)
- multiple mentions/appearances/instances in the same episode/film count as one

What is admitted:

- refits are the same ship
- mentions of the ship in dialog
- on-screen mentions/representations of the ship on displays
- we need positive identification.   The ship must be positively identifiable.   For example, in a battle or debris scene, we must be able to either see the name or serial number or it must be mentioned in dialog.   No speculating that it's "probably a certain ship".   The basis for that speculation would usually already count as a mention (e.g. previous dialog)
- parallel universes, hallucinations, Q-creations, etc are in-bounds as long as it represents 'the same ship form the same era'

---

> **COMMENTS ON THE GIVEN ANSWERS**
>
> It's become clear I'm not going to make anyone happy by selecting an answer.
>
> - There is a legitimate position that @Valorum's answer, the USS Leeds, is not a suitable answer because (a) he needed to use out of universe information to identify the ship and especially (b) appearing in the credit sequence doesn't qualify as a recurring role
> - There is a legitimate position that @Praxis's answer of the Stargazer in over a hundred episode because a model appears in Picards's ready room is not a suitable answer because that's not a recurring role either.   For example, if Picard had a picture of Kirk on his wall, would we say that Kirk has a recurring role in hundreds of episodes?
> - Of the remaining answers, it looks like @kl78's answer of the Rotarran has the biggest role.
> - I actually believe @Shwern's answer may be the most useful one, but since it doesn't currently subsume @kl78's answer, it can't be correct.
>
> I have my personal position on when I try to focus on the intent of the question, but others get upset when I clarify after they've already given answers.   Therefore I will **not accept** an answer and I ask everyone please just acknowledge there are merits to all the answers and we'll leave it at that.   Everyone please just enjoy yourselves -- I think all the answers are interesting.

Comment: Countdown to people not reading the text and answering "Enterprise" in 3. 2. 1....

Comment: also if you dont tag it technically ds9 and the earth space dock are ships, though they lack warp.

Comment: @Himarm:   No, technically there are not ships, even though they may have some propulsion.   And that's against the intent anyhow.   Furthermore, it should be clear that DS9 is not valid because it is not "recurring", it is main cast, like Enterprises and Voyager.   I will edit to remove the debate.

Comment: @MrLister:  Heh, I suppose you could make that argument, but the concept is that just like we have main cast and recurring roles for actors, there's a notion of recurring roles for ships.

Comment: How do we know that ships mentioned in dialogue are the same ship?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Ahhh, I hadn't made that distinction between main roles and recurring roles. Yes, it's clear now.

Comment: @user001:    Because you apply some reasonable common sense.      How do you know it's the same Adm. Nechayev whenever someone mentions her?   If there's a mention two years apart, and there's no indication the ship was destroyed and a new ship christened in that timeframe, then you reasonably assume it is the same ship.

Comment: There's some starship with blow-dryers for nacelles that appears in the two of the films.  Does that count? :-)

Comment: Are we counting off screen things like scene deceptions in official scripts, close ups of production models, and statements from prominent production staff? Or are the episodes to be treated as "historical documents"?

Comment: Aren't all Borg cubes essentially the same thing? ;)

Comment: @ThePopMachine USS Intrepid (NCC-38907) • USS Intrepid (NCC-74600)
Two Intrepid named ships (one that rescued Worf and one which Geordi was in competition with). One would also assume that there is an NX Intrepid for the class of ship for Voyager.

That's two ships of the same name and common sense indicates that there was a third. Without ship registry number, visuals or a class designation how are you sure...

Comment: What does the word "prolific" mean in the title of your question?

Comment: @user14111: read the question text for a full explanation of the question.   That's what it's for

Comment: @user14111, okay,  well I would have thought you could get it from the context or from googling it.   "Prolific" means abundant or plentiful.   Technically, I've used it pretty imprecisely here, which is what I thought you were calling me out on.  I couldn't think of a better single-word choice at the time.

Comment: Are ships the official designations of which are unknown but are certainly the same ship admissible? I feel that the ST:ENT's "Xindi weapon" (third, final iteration), though not known by its official name, owns the most mentions/views of the same vessel, giving it the unequivocal most appearances. It was a ship (self propelled, had a crew), and was I think in 15+- eps of ENT. May I submit this as an answer?; the question stands as "what ship appears..", not "which ship we know the official name of appears.." Anyway, if isn't right—in my view—it belongs here with the contenders. Thanks!

Comment: @thomas, yes, it's not important to know the name of the ship if we know it's the same ship.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : You updated the question with the Kirk on the wall analogy, but you should remove the bit about it not necessarily being the Stargazer.  Rick Sternbach already confirmed it is and you and I already discussed this.

Comment: @Praxis:   No problem.

Comment: Aren't all Borg cubes the same one?

Answer (score 82):

The 'Nebula-Class' [USS Leeds](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Leeds) appears in no fewer than [104 episodes of DS9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsOE73pxpys).

[image]

[image]

Comment: /drops the mike.

Comment: If I gave upvotes to people with more rep than me, I'd upvote this.

Comment: @Richard:   Okay, okay, very tricky  (Of course Richard is referring to the fact this ship is in the opening credit sequence for *DS9*)

Comment: I upvote for the creativity (and to help get the word out that that ship is not the Enterprise D) in spite of the fact that this doesn't meet the criteria of the question. Also for the [freehand circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/147335) which help make it clear.

Comment: @corsiKa this perfectly meets the criteria.

Comment: @Himarm I'm afraid that it doesn't. It's not a real ship so it's not a refit, it's not a mention in the dialog, there's no on-screen mention, it's not a parallel universe trick, and while it is positively identifiable using out-of-universe information it's not positively identifiable by just watching the show - just that it's Nebula class. Furthermore, *it has no role* and thus is not a *recurring role*.

Comment: @corsiKa http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Leeds the name is clear in the ending credits, and its a real ship. therefor it counts by the questions standards

Comment: You're missing the part where it doesn't have *a role*. "Recurring characters often play major roles in more than one episode, sometimes being the main focus" This hunk of metal never plays a role nor is ever mentioned in any episode.

Comment: @corsiKa role: an actors part in a play or a movie, this ship has a role, its very minor, but its filling the part of a ship docking at ds9, the question doesn't ask for major reoccurring ship, just a prolific reoccurring ship. its essentially the of the tree you give to the socially awkward kid in grade school at the school play.

Comment: @corsiKa If you aren't going to accept the Leeds because it lacks a role in the opening, then you can't in good faith accept mentions of a ship that are unrelated to the appearance of said ship. If a character is simply mentioned in an episode they wouldn't be said to have had a role in the episode. Example: Gowron is a major recurring character, that is often mentioned without ever appearing in the episode.

Comment: @Xantec Different. He's actually mentioned in the episode. That's a role. The ship just being in the opening credits (which have nothing to do with the actual episode) is completely different.

Comment: @corsiKa I think you are using the word "role" wrong if mentioning someone who doesn't appear in the episode counts as filling a role. That said, I agree that the opening credits don't count. Mostly because it is the SAME APPEARANCE EACH TIME. It isn't 'recurring' in any meaningful sense of the word.

Comment: @Shane I also agree that it isn't recurring. As for the whole "mentioning = role" thing, that's simply because of the second bullet point in the question that says mentioning is accepted. I would not normally consider a mention to be a role, only within the context of this question.

Comment: @corsiKa It probably isn't what the asker intended, but it isn't excluded explicitly by any of the criteria. That's a problem with the question, not the answer, imo.

Comment: @jpmc26 It's not a problem with the question. It's a problem with the answer. The opening credits are not part of the episode.

Comment: @corsiKa The question does not make that distinction. It is almost certainly not what the OP intended, but there is no explicit statement of opening credits being excluded. If someone writes a question with such detailed criteria as this one, it's their own fault if they left holes in it. Is this answer a little facetious? Sure, but the fact we can even have a discussion about whether this is a legitimate answer suggests that the question was poor to begin with. I'm sorry, but that's what someone gets when they try to take a too broad question and narrow it down using lawyer-like criteria.

Comment: @corsiKa [SAG](http://www.sagaftra.org/) would strenuously disagree with you on that point.  Possibly with lawsuits.  ;)

Comment: Surely since the credits are always repeating the same scene, this should only count as one?

Comment: @Leushenko Is there any indication one way or the other that this depiction of the Leeds in intended to be the same one in every instance of the opening credits (aside from the out of universe possibility that it is actually the same footage reused)?  I mean, maybe the Leeds just visits DS9 every episode...

Comment: @Michael - It also visits DS9 the whole time it's occupied by the Dominion.

Comment: Why only 104 out of the series' 176 episodes?

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - The USS Leeds wasn't seen in the opening credits until Season 4 - ([Seasons 1-3 opening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TsMyLt2BTM) vs [Season 4-7 opening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqoREh9cVfM))

Answer (score 55):

**The USS Stargazer** appears in **at least 150 episodes of *The Next Generation*.**

[image]

According to [this interview](https://books.google.ca/books?id=JCbTA9wMmEAC&pg=PT116&lpg=PT116&dq=uss+stargazer+model+in+ready+room&source=bl&ots=8hSm70a81w&sig=yzHfiREue7IpV2MDjil04Mt0NUo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCWoVChMIs739k7GiyAIViXA-Ch3eGAGb#v=onepage&q=uss%20stargazer%20model%20in%20ready%20room&f=false) with Rich Sternbach (a designer on *TNG* and co-author of the *TNG Technical Manual*), the model is the Stargazer, Picard's first command.

Comment: I challenge you to go through the trouble of proving it actually appears in every episode.    Anyways, no, I won't take Richard's or your tricky answers.   But I will smile at them.

Comment: Isn't that the model referenced in [Shwern's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104145/31051)?

Comment: @Praxis I think 178 is wrong. There is a *different* model in some episodes that I suspect is supposed to be the Enterprise-A

Comment: @JasonBaker : Ah, I didn't see that part of Schwern's answer, only the 10 verbal mentions in his answer.  I will do my duty and delete this!  Thanks for pointing that out.  :-)

Comment: I don't think I'd delete it; it is still *a* ship, after all. Though I'm not sure how well it fits the question's criteria, given that we don't have a name for it

Comment: @JasonBaker : Okay, I'll leave it for now.  I'm fairly certain it is a representation of the Stargazer, given the design and the fact that Picard captained it prior to the Enterprise.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield : The models certainly stabilized after Season 1 (at least as I recall), so I'm chopping off > 20 from the total, and will verify in the meantime.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Making people smile is all I aspire to in life. Anyways, a model is a "representations of a ship", just not an on-screen representation.

Comment: @Praxis:   Well, to that I'd say, you don't actually know what ship that is.  Then your proper answer should be **this guy** -- uh -- I mean **this ship**

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I'd love to put **this ship**, but I've found confirmation that it is the Stargazer.  Now in answer.

Comment: Clearly a support craft for the enterprise.  It supports the ship by decorating its captain's cabin.

Comment: Does it also appear in the First Contact movie?

Comment: @jpmc26 : I'm not certain --- that might be the Enterprises only.  I'll check though, thanks. :-)

Comment: *A* model is not *the* ship. *A model of the USS...*

Comment: @Mazura : The picture makes it clear I am talking about the model.  Also, the question says that "representations of ships" are okay.  :-)

Comment: If only I was using a computer with a browser that would load those pictures... You could say, *The USS S.G. is represented...* To the best of my knowledge, *the* ship has never appeared onscreen. I'm just being pedant, take it as you will.

Comment: @Mazura : But the ship *did* appear on-screen.  It appeared in ["The Battle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Battle_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)), when a Ferengi captain gave it back to Picard as a "gift".

Comment: @Mazura Of course, out of universe, many (all?) of the ships we actually saw represented as real ships *were* models. :-)

Comment: If mentions and schematic displays are explicitly permitted then a model certainly is as well. The mere presence of the model keeps "mentioning" that Picard was once on the Stargazer

Comment: If Picard had a picture of Kirk on his wall, would we say that Kirk has a recurring role in hundreds of episodes?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I'd have to say yes, because you wrote that "on-screen mentions / representations on displays" are okay.  By your definition, an image of Kirk on a display in a bunch of episodes is a recurring role, but a print picture is not....

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I don't care about acceptance, mind you.  (Schwern should get it.) I just have issue with inconsistency in the requirements.  Also, the latest comment about Kirk (which I believe does not apply because of the permitting of display representations) has probably attracted a downvote.

Answer (score 51):

Here's a list of starships I recall being mentioned a lot, plus other people's suggestions, and how many times they appear in the transcripts.

- [USS Stargazer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Stargazer): [10](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22Stargazer%22)
- [IKS Rotarran](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/IKS_Rotarran): [9](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22Rotarran%22) (Memory Alpha says 13, possibly based on official script notes)
- [NX-02 Columbia](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Columbia): [8](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net%2FEnterprise+columbia)
- [USS Potemkin (TNG/DS9 era)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Potemkin_%28Excelsior_class%29): [6](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22Potemkin%22)
- [USS Hood](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Hood_%28Excelsior_class%29): [5](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net%2Fnextgen%2F+hood)
- [USS Excelsior](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Excelsior): [5](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22Excelsior%22)
- [Seleya](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Seleya): [4](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22Seleya%22)
- [USS Bozeman](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Bozeman): [4](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22Bozeman%22)
- [USS Endeavor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Endeavour_%28NCC-71805%29): 4 (Solid references in Memory Alpha).
- [USS Potemkin (TOS-era)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Potemkin_%28NCC-1657%29): [3](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22Potemkin%22)
- [USS Saratoga](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Saratoga_%28NCC-31911%29): [3](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Saratoga_%28NCC-31911%29) (Possibly more given how many times they replay Sisko's Wolf 359 flashbacks in DS9)
- [USS Farragut](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Farragut_%28Excelsior_class%29): [2](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Achakoteya.net%20columbia#hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22Farragut%22) (There are multiple Farraguts, and the one in Generations is not the one in DS9)

If you count only what we see and hear on screen, it's probably Stargazer, though it's only seen once. If you include notes in official scripts, it's probably Rotarran.

If you count the model on Picard's desk, it would appear Stargazer wins hands down. However, [apparently that is not the Stargazer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Stargazer#Background_information) and it's never referred to as such.

Comment: +1 Also, I see now that you had already pointed out the Stargazer model (which technically counts, given the wording of the question).   :-)

Comment: As long as your listing runner-ups, I'm counting 6 mentions of Riker's previous assignment, the USS Potemkin (5 in TNG, and once in DS9).

Comment: @CalebHines Good spot. I also added its TOS counterpart.

Comment: The first name that popped into my head was *"Bozeman"*. Suggested an edit to add its four appearances.

Comment: What about the Borg cube?

Comment: @Mazura There are many [Borg Cubes](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Borg_cube) and it's usually not possible tell one cube from another. For example, we don't know if the cube in Q Who is the same as in Best Of Both Worlds. I can't think of a single instance (aside from two-parters) where the same Cube appears in two episodes, can you?

Comment: Here's another thought: what about Chakotay's Maqui ship? A cursory search found that it wasn't given a proper name in Voyager's pilot episode, though it's name was later shown on a screen as the _Val Jean_ (so that's at least two episodes). It's been a while since I've watched Voyager, but I wonder how many other episodes, especially in season 1, might have Chakotay or one of his crew referring to it (e.g. "On my ship..."), or might even contain flashbacks.

Comment: Kudos for completeness, but you've left out the Defiant (NCC-1764) which appears in 3 episodes, one TOS and a two-parter ENT.

Comment: Also, I don't recall if the Sao Paulo appeared and was renamed to the (DS9) Defiant within the same episode, so it might have appeared as something other than the Defiant more than once.

Comment: @Jherico USS Defiant is clever, but I'm not going for a complete list of any ship mentioned in more than one episode. The lower numbered ones are ships which somebody else mentioned but didn't provide sources.

Comment: @Jherico [Sao Paulo is only mentioned once](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22sao+paulo%22) as the Sao Paulo. You can do the searches, too.

Answer (score 35):

My guess would be the IKS Rotarran. According [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/IKS_Rotarran) it has 13 appearances in DS9 Episodes.

[image]

(DS9 Season 5)
    "Soldiers of the Empire" 
    "Call to Arms"

(DS9 Season 6)
 "A Time to Stand" 
    "Sons and Daughters"
    "Favor the Bold"
    "Sacrifice of Angels"
    "You Are Cordially Invited"
    "Tears of the Prophets"

(DS9 Season 7)
 "Shadows and Symbols" 
    "The Emperor's New Cloak"
    "Inter Arma Enim Silent Leges"
    "Penumbra"
    "Tacking Into the Wind"

Comment: I only count nine in the transcripts. For example, it isn't mentioned in [A Time To Stand](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/525.htm). I'll have to rewatch the episodes.

Comment: @schwern: I must admit, i only checked memory alpha for this post. I did see all DS9 episodes and remembered the ship is seen often, but did not count by myself. Not sure how reliable the linked post is. But we are talking about "positive identification", maybe it is only visible for a short time in the episodes without further mention or only an interior shot.

Comment: @schwern: maybe in a time to stand it only references to this: http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Defiant_and_Rotarran_at_Starbase_375.jpg
Its also mentioned in this transcript:http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/525.txt

Comment: Official script > transcript. :)

Comment: The link to the script i posted should provide the official script, according to the webmaster of the page.Can not see what makes your linked script more official then mine linked, but i must admit i am no expert in this.

Comment: I'm agreeing with you.

Comment: @schwern: ok, sry then, understood your comment wrong^^, thx richard for the clarification, did not know that

Answer (score 15):

Another strong contender is Chakotay's Maquis ship, the *[Val Jean](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Val_Jean)*. Oddly enough, it's name is never spoken (making transcript searches much more difficult!), but it is seen on a computer screen in one episode. While its *crew* is referenced heavily throughout the series, I count **at least 10 or 11 episodes** where the actual ship is mentioned (depending on if you count *Caretaker* as one or two episodes). Without rewatching the whole series, I can't guarantee there aren't more.

- 1x01/02 - *Caretaker* - The ship has a prominent role, and is destroyed.
- 1x03 - *Parallax* - Chakotay asks Janeway if she'd have served him if they "were on the Maquis ship now instead of Voyager"
- 1x11 - *State of Flux* - Chakotay, commenting on Tuvok's and Seska's both being spies, asks "Was anyone on board that ship working for me?"
- 1x16 - *Learning Curve* - An ex-Maqui tells Tuvok "On our ship, when something went wrong, you fixed it," to which Tuvok replies he is "no longer on a Maquis ship."
- 2x05 - *Non Sequiter* - Paris tells Kim that Janeway asked him to "help her track down that Maquis ship".
- 5x24 - *Relativity* - An admiral assures Janeway that Tuvok is "aboard Chakotay's ship."
- 6x09 - *The Voyager Conspiracy* - Seven believes Chakotay was deliberately trying to use the Caretaker array as a weapon against the Federation, "offering his vessel as bait". Janeway tells Seven that "Tuvok was a spy on Chakotay's ship."
- 6x25 - *The Haunting of Deck Twelve* - Chakotay admits he "used to have long conversations with my Maquis ship."
- 7x04 - *Repression* - The name of the ship, *Val Jean*, is seen on a computer screen.
- 7x11 - *Shattered* - Janeway tells a time-displaced Chakotay that "we're about to chase your ship into the Badlands".

Of course, admitting oblique references like "my/your/that ship" might also increase the number for some of the other contenders.

[image]

[image]

---

EDIT: Sticking with the same series, and going for runner-ups, Neelix's "freighter" the *[Baxial](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Baxial)*, was apparently shown or mentioned in **8** different episodes, according to memory alpha. Granted, this may count as a support ship or shuttle, given that it fit within Voyager's shuttlebay.

Answer (score 14):

[image: USS Stargazer]

Based only on googling

> site:chakoteya.net Stargazer

It appears Capt Picard's previous command, the **USS Stargazer**, is mentioned in at least **ten episodes**:

"The Battle", "Relics", "The Wounded", "Allegiance", "The Measure of a Man", "Chain of Command", "The Child", "Coming of Age", "Tapestry", and "Family"

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head I'd guess Excelsior, Farragut, Hood or Endeavor.

A brief [wiki search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_Starfleet_starships_ordered_by_class#Excelsior_class) of those:

- Hood: five mentions in TNG and DS9.