# Which (non-Earth) planet appears in the most Star Trek episodes?

Tags: star-trek, planets

### Which planet, other than Earth, appears in the most episodes of *Star Trek*?

Clarifications:

- "appears" means a scene in the episode is actually set there (mention of a planet is not sufficient)
- versions of the same planet in parallel universes count as the same planet for counting purposes
- all TV series of Star Trek (TOS, TNG, DS9, VOY, ENT, TAS) are included, but **not the movies**

Comment: There isn't actually any problems if you don't specify it - if you say that *TAS* and the movies count, then Vulcan wins, otherwise if you discount the movies and *TAS* then Bajor is the correct answer.  Your original question did stipulate **episodes**, meaning the movies don't count.  It's entirely up to you, but because one is 17 and the other 16, only one can be correct - the choice is yours!

Comment: @randal'thor : Saw your ping --- thanks!  I'm not sure I can improve upon TheDoc's answers.  If the films are allowed, Vulcan should be the winner; otherwise, Bajor, considering that *DS9* is set in proximity of Bajor and there are about 180 episodes to work with.  Perhaps the surprising thing is how *little* we see Bajor considering how many *DS9* episodes there are.

Comment: @Praxis very true; I was completely shocked to find Bajor was seen so few times throughout the series - DS9 is literally right on top of the planet for goodness' sake!

Comment: @randal'thor, this sounds like a question @ ThePopMachine would write

Comment: I wouldn't have excluded movies completely, but mentioned that it should be differentiated, because now it's possible to duplicate the question just by including movies.

Comment: @ThePopMachine It certainly does! ;-)

Comment: I'd be surprised if Earth appears more times than Bajor. You could probably have left that out of the question and gotten the same answer.

Comment: “DS9 is literally right on top of the planet for goodness' sake!” It is in the opening episode, but by the end they’ve moved it to the mouth of the wormhole. It’s not far, but it’s not in orbit of the planet any more. (How we end up seeing Bajor three times in *Voyager* is beyond me.)

Comment: @ToddWilcox, that I very much doubt that

Comment: @ToddWilcox TOS had at least *City on the Edge of Forever* and *Assignment: Earth*, TNG had at least *Family*, *The First Duty*, and *Time's Arrow*, DS9 has those two changeling infiltration eps plus *Far Beyond the Stars*, VOY has the Reg Barclay arc (3 eps), and ENT has at least the premiere, the finale, and Carbon Creek. That's 14 or 15 (does Time's Arrow count for one or two?) If there are one or two more I forgot across five series, then it's a tie.

Comment: (and I didn't watch most of ENT, but I bet they went back to Earth more times than that...)

Comment: More: *All Good Things...* has scenes on Earth.

Comment: Ok I give! :-) They didn't stand out in my memory.

Comment: @ToddWilcox just sayin', Earth is the only planet with Sisko's Creole Kitchen.

Comment: Talos IV. Every episode of every incarnation of the show took place on Talos IV. The fact that the crew thought they were on other planets was merely an illusion put in their minds by the Talosians. Wrong thinking will be punished.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think it must be **Cardassia Prime**, which we see **18 times**:

twice in TNG episodes:

- "Chain of Command", part 1
- "Chain of Command", part 2

and in sixteen times DS9 episodes:

- "Tribunal"
- "Second Skin"
- "Defiant"
- "Trials and Tribble-ations"
- "By Inferno's Light"
- "Tears of the Prophets"
- "Image in the Sand"
- "Shadows and Symbols"
- "Treachery, Faith and the Great River"
- "Penumbra"
- "'Til Death Do Us Part"
- "Strange Bedfellows"
- "The Changing Face of Evil"
- "Tacking Into the Wind"
- "The Dogs of War"
- "What You Leave Behind"

See the [Memory Alpha page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cardassia_Prime).

Comment: "Trials and Tribble-ations" is a little arguable; it just has a scene where the *Defiant* is in orbit around Cardassia Prime. But even if you left it out, that's still more than Bajor has. Great find! This deserves way more upvotes than my answer...

Comment: @Micah: the list is from the Memory Alpha page, they included that episode; I maybe wouldn't have either.

Answer (score 52):

This one:

[image: Voyager credits planet]

It clearly is not Earth, since it has rings, and I do believe it appears (and is not just mentioned) in the credits sequence of every single *Voyager* episode.

DS9 and TNG both have a few more episodes than VOY. However:

- TNG revamped their credits in season 3. The season 1/2 credits include shots of Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn; the later-season credits include only a shot of a single gas giant which is neither Jupiter (its rings are too visible) nor Saturn (it's the wrong color).
- DS9's credits include no planets. Note however that the natural celestial body which appears in the largest number of *Star Trek* episodes is almost certainly the comet which begins the DS9 credits (which appears to be consistently the same object even through a credit revamp).

Comment: you're pushing the definition of "in" there a bit.

Comment: Boo!  for tricky technical answer and for the same style of answer as @Richard's http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104146/3823 .  Plus, if you're going to be technical, there is no "scene set there"

Comment: This is like saying the Columbia Pictures Lady is the most prolific actress.

Comment: Does Bajor not appear in the DS9 credits?  I'll have to watch those closely again.

Comment: The "This guy" of planets!

Comment: @DarrelHoffman *Deep Space* Nine!

Comment: Hmm, does the opening credits count as "a scene?"

Comment: Is that the unnamed planet from the episode *Emanations*?

Comment: Hmm. I forget. Does TNG have two different openings? There's lots of planets in there.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Honestly, this question was just begging for an answer like this if it wasn't stated that open credits are excluded after the answer you linked to.

Comment: @jpmc26, no it really isn't!   This site is not a contest to see who can win with the trickiest answer.   I realize it goes against everyone's inclination because we are overwhelmingly nerds here,  but people should be giving and upvoting **useful** answers,  which means using one's brain to infer the reasonable intent of a question without the questioner needing to spell out every annoying restriction.

Comment: @jpmc26, but if you do insist on being technical,  this is technically doubly wrong because it is neither part of the episode not it is the location of a scene.   Shame on everyone!

Comment: @ThePopMachine it's answers like this that forced PPCG to come up with an entire list of "stupid things you think it's funny to pretend are answers but aren't and just make you look like a jerk" that are implicitly included in every question. I hope we're not at that point here :(

Comment: That planet looks like Neptune.  I have seen several pictures in which Neptune has small rings.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield, link?

Comment: @MikeEdenfield, to your point, to clarify my position,  I don't think it makes people  look like a jerk, but I do think the self-propagating circlejerk is detrimental to the site overall.

Comment: @ThePopMachine true, I don't think we're at the "jerk" level yet, but PPCG seemed to be and I'd like not to get us there: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default

Answer (score 49):

## Bajor

I'm going for Bajor, seen **16 times**:

- "Chain of Command, Part I" - *TNG*
- "Birthright, Part I" - *TNG*
- "Emissary" - *DS9*
- "The Circle" - *DS9*
- "The Siege" - *DS9*
- "Cardassians" - *DS9*
- "The Collaborator" - *DS9*
- "Past Tense, Part I" - *DS9*
- "Shakaar" - *DS9*
- "Rapture" - *DS9*
- "The Reckoning" - *DS9*
- "The Changing Face of Evil" - *DS9*
- "What You Leave Behind" - *DS9*
- "Maneuvers" - *VOY*
- "Nothing Human" - *VOY*
- "Flesh and Blood" - *VOY*

Comment: I don't know if that's the maximum, but Cardassia Prime appears more often than Bajor: there are two appearences in TNG, and 16 in DS9. See here: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Cardassia_Prime

Comment: @JanJohannsen excellent find!  Please post this as your own answer and may a thousand up votes rain down upon you!

Comment: @JanJohannsen no longer! Now go forth and post good sir!

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote!

Comment: Because the correct answer to "Which (non-Earth) planet appears in the most Star Trek episodes?" is not Bajor, but [Cardassia Prime](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/107392/5789).

Comment: @CeesTimmerman that's like saying in a 'first of' question because someone puts an answer which isn't the first of, but among the answers at the time it was, it deserves to be downvoted!  I disagree with that line of thought completely

Comment: Me too, more so because i hate flawed analogies and the fact that the correct answer still has fewer votes than this incorrect one.

Answer (score 21):

## Vulcan

**Edit**: Now that the movies don't count, this isn't *the* correct answer, but is still valid within the scope of the question!

Possibly the planet Vulcan, seen **12** times:

- "Amok Time' - *TOS*
- 'Journey to Babel - *TOS*
- 'Yesteryear' - *TAS*
- 'Sarek' - *TNG*
- 'Unification I'  *TNG*
- 'Gambit II'  *TNG*
- 'Persistence of Vision' - *VOY*
- 'Gravity' - *VOY*
- 'Home' - *ENT*
- 'The Forge' - *ENT*
- 'Awakening' - *ENT*
- 'Kir'Shara' - *ENT*