# Which (non-Earth) planet appears in the most Babylon 5 episodes?

Tags: babylon-5, planets

I was inspired by this question: [Which (non-Earth) planet appears in the most Star Trek episodes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107218/) to ask the same for Babylon 5.

I'll also adopt the same rules:

- "appears" means a scene in the episode is actually set there (mention of a planet is not sufficient)
- versions of the same planet in parallel universes count as the same planet for counting purposes (not sure if this will affect the outcome in B5)
- both Babylon 5 and Crusade are included, but not the movies

Off the top of my head, I would probably say Centauri Prime or Mars, but I'm really not sure!

Comment: If you don't count Epsilon 3 or Mars, it's probably the Drazi homeworld. I recall four or five episodes set there in the later seasons.

Comment: I don't think the Drazi homeworld appears at all until season 5. Whereas Centauri Prime appears a lot, particularly during seasons 4 and 5, but even in earlier seasons.

Comment: The list might go, from most-to-least, Mars, Centauri Prime, maybe a tie between Minbar and Drazi Home, Narn, and Z'ha'dum (if Sheridan's limbo was there)?

Comment: @JoeL. +1 for saying "if Sheridan's limbo was there", which was never really established apart from "the space between tick and tock" - I completely forgot that! I'd be surprised if Mars was seen more than Centauri Prime. If anyone has statistics similar to the answers on the equivalent Star Trek question, I'd be very interested!

Comment: If you do want more counts beyond the obvious answer, The Midwinter guide has detailed synopsis pages, and they do appear to go scene by scene.  I'd started trying to add them up, but didn't get far before I got busy with something else (and the 1st season apparently didn't budget much for other planets).

Answer (score 8):

I think it would have to be [Epsilon 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_locations_in_Babylon_5#Epsilon_III) the planet B5 orbits.

[image]

Comment: I'd classify planetary orbit as a different location than the planet itself. There are only a few episodes where they actually visit the planet that they're in orbit of; after all, they purposefully built B5 in orbit around a dead world so that it would be neutral territory.

Comment: @db48x good point! I'd be interested in answers about what planet is actually the most visited. The criteria states "a scene in the episode is actually set there", which is surely different from just being seen from orbit!

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be Mars, Epsilon III they only go to twice, where as Mars they go there a lot more.

Comment: Funny thing is I have never actually watched this show, some guy in a line next to me gave me this answer.

Comment: I'd still go with Centauri Prime though

Answer (score 1):

Centauri Prime. We [the audience] regularly visit Centauri Prime throughout all five seasons of B5. One could argue that Mars is the most-visited, but that's only because it becomes a main setting point for Stephen, Marcus, Lyta, and Garibaldi in Season 4. Centauri Prime is also heavily featured in Season 4 and Season 5, and we see it numerous times throughout all the other seasons.

Centauri Prime. Hands down [hair up].